# TableViewController Calls Parser message but doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss-reader

I'm writing an XML feed reader and my viewController isn't messaging the parser properly.

I have a print statement in the parseFeedWithResults message that isn't printing and items remains null after the call.

I even made a dummy message in the parser class I made that would only print something when called and that doesn't print either.

What's the issue?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSLog(@"at viewDidLoad");
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.title = @"Feeds";
        [self loadItems];
        [parser testMessage: kFeedURL];
    }

    - (void)loadItems
    {
        NSLog(@"At loadItems");
        self.items= [parser parseFeedWithResults:[NSURL URLWithString:kFeedURL]];
        NSLog(@"Passed parser initialization, parse: %@", self.items);
    }
```

Comment: did you create a parser object? What happens if you log parser?